# Enviar una imagen usando JSON en node.js (express) a un dispositivo android

Tags: android, nodejs, express, url

Estoy tratando de enviar una imagen al cliente usando un servidor en node.js. Cuando escribo la URL en un browser me toma la imagen. Sin embargo, cuando la quiero obtener en el celular, no me aparece.

Este es el codigo para enviar la url de la imagen:

```
app.use(express.static('images'));
app.post('/Imagen',function(req, res){
    var dir= "http://10.0.0.23:8080/basket.png";
    var obj={"img":dir};
    res.json(obj);
});
```

Este codigo, al recibir un String con el JSON (que funciona) se lo manda a una clase llamada LeerConsulta la cual lee el objeto JSON y obtiene la imagen:

```
public class Accedido extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imagen;
    Button ok;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accedido);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        imagen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Img);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bitmap img=null;
                Ajax im=new Ajax();
                try {
                    String imagen = im.execute(MainActivity.IP_ADDRESS + "Imagen").get();
                    Toast.makeText(Accedido.this, imagen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    LeerConsulta lec = new LeerConsulta(imagen, "img");
                }
                catch(Exception exc) {
                    Toast.makeText(Accedido.this, exc.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                imagen.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
        });
    }
```

Por último, este es el codigo que lee el objeto JSON y recibe la imagen:

```
public class LeerConsulta{

    static String content="", data="";

    public LeerConsulta(String Content, String Dat)
    {
        content=Content;
        data=Dat;
    }
    protected Bitmap getBitMap()
    {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
            String src=jsonResponse.getString(data);
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();
            InputStream input=con.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String err="EL error es este: ";
            Log.e(err,e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿La idea es que se pueda acceder al directorio de las imágenes? Ten en cuenta que Node.js no es como Apache. Para pruebas locales está bien, pero si piensas implementarlo es mejor poner una ruta para `/images/:name` y enviar la imagen con `response#sendFile`.

Comment: pasa que por una cuestion de proligidad para el proyecto que quiero hacer, me conviene enviar por JSON las cosas. Entonces hago eso de res.JSON(); ahi logre que me reconozca el buscador la imagen al escribir en el buscador `http://10.0.0.23:8080/basket.png` directamente

Comment: ¿Execute solamente obtiene el JSON? En `leerConsulta` supongo haces la petición para obtener la imagen. ¿Puedes mostar ese código?

Comment: @guzgarcia la ultima parte de codigo que escribi ahi es leerConsulta

Comment: Por lo que investigue, es mejor hacer Drawable las cosas igual...Convendria hacer el codigo con eso en lugar de bitMap

Comment: De Android con Java no sé mucho. Pero dime, ¿obtienes respuesta? Si no, es posible que se deba a que no le has dado permisos en el manifest.

Comment: Creo que el unico permiso que necesita es internet (el cual ya lo tiene). Cuando escribo en el browser del servidor la url de la cual se obtiene la imagen, me la reconoce. El tema ahora es android principalmente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51474/discussion-between-guzgarcia-and-f-riggio).

Answer (score 1):

Node.js no es como apache, donde puedes tener directorios públicos ver el contenido de las carpetas. Cuando haces un directorio estático en Express, lo que estás haciendo es poner a disponibilidad los archivos dentro.

> Express busca los archivos relativos al directorio estático, por lo que el nombre del directorio estático no forma parte del URL.

Cuando entra una petición, primero se evalúan las rutas que se han asociado al servidor; en caso no exista, procede a buscar en los archivos estáticos.

En caso quieras mantener la ruta inicial, debes de crear una carpeta y hacer que se sirva ésta, finalmente poner la carpeta `images` dentro:

```
assets
|__images
   |__basket.png
   |__football.png
   |__tenis.png
```

Y sirves ésta carpeta:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
```

Ahora si accedes a `http://10.0.0.23:8080/images/basket.png` verás que se te sirve la imagen correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora lo voy a tener en cuenta. Igual el problema ahora es otro (frontend) ya que logre obtener una URL que me muestre la imagen (la probe desde el celular y funciona), pero cuando quiero que la app la baje no me la reconoce. Ahora edito la pregunta y pongo el codigo de android (si me pueden dar una mano con eso). Ahora modifico la pregunta como para que me aparezca el problema actual

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta. Si pueden ayudarme se los agradeceria mucho